# Applying Pyspark pipeline on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark pipeline (containing imputations and a machine learning model) and a pandas dataframe. Can I apply the pipeline on this pandas dataframe without converting it to Pyspark dataframe? If not possible, how do I efficiently use the pyspark pipeline to generate the predictions on pandas dataframe?

Comment: Just for clarification: what is the reason not to convert to spark? It is one function call `spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)`. And back to pandas `spark_result_df.select("*").toPandas()`

Comment: It's a business requirement @Michael Szczesny

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it is not possible to do so. Pyspark models are not working the same way as other python libraries such as Sk-Learn etc. You will need a Spark data frame for Spark Pipeline(s) or/and ML models. Also, at the same time, you usually use Spark [PySpark] because you want to distribute your competition. [Pandas run operations on a single machine whereas PySpark runs on multiple machines. If you are working on a Machine Learning application where you are dealing with larger datasets, PySpark is the best fit which could processes operations many times(100x) faster than Pandas.]

You can read here in the documentation that you need a spark [SQL] data frame:

- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html#main-concepts-in-pipelines
- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html#dataframe

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response @SamL. I also wanted to know if it is possible to convert this Pyspark pipeline (or atleast the model within it) to python?

Comment: What do you mean with convert to python? There are already other libraries such as, Sk-learn which has both pipeline and different ml models. The best would be to convert your Pandas df to Spark df.

Comment: I have a spark pipeline and a pandas dataframe. I can't apply the spark pipeline on the pandas dataframe. I also can't convert the pandas dataframe to spark dataframe because of business requirements. So, I'm trying to see if we can convert the pipeline to pandas and apply it on the pandas dataframe.